# How to identify an outlier from a data set in R

Tags: r, statistics, outliers

So I am new to R and I am currently trying to identify outliers in a set of data, so far I have inputted into R,

```
lifespan_yrs<- c(38.6, 4.5, 14, 8, 69, 27, 19, 30.4, 28, 50, 7, 30, 3.5,
 40, 3.5, 50, 6, 10.4, 34, 7, 28, 20, 3.9, 39.3, 41, 16.2, 9, 7.6, 46, 22.4, 
 16.3, 2.6, 24, 100, 13, 10, 3.2, 2, 5, 6.5, 23.6, 12, 20.2, 13, 27, 18, 13.7, 
 4.7, 9.8, 29, 7, 6, 17, 20, 12.7, 3.5, 4.5, 7.5, 2.3, 24, 3, 13)

gestation_days<- c(645, 42, 60, 25, 624, 180, 35, 392, 63, 230, 112, 281, 35, 
365, 42, 28, 42, 120, 75, 122, 400, 148, 16, 252, 310, 63, 28, 68, 336, 100, 33, 
 21.5, 50, 267, 30, 45, 19, 30, 12, 120, 440, 140, 170, 17, 115, 31, 63, 21, 52, 
164, 225, 225, 150, 151, 90, 45, 60, 200, 46, 210, 14, 38)

lifespan_yrs

gestation_days

plot(gestation_days,lifespan_yrs)
```

And I have a plot of this data, however the next part of the question says "investigate this plot and discuss any data points that merit investigation" I am taking this to mean are there any outliers in the data (I am not sure what definition of an outlier i can/should use) and then is there a way on R to investigate the data points in such a way?
Please use simple language to explain this as, again, I am new to R.

Thank you! Mollie x

Comment: If you are asking for how to define outliers, that is really a statistical question that would be better asked on http://stats.stackexchange.com/. If you have a definition that you want to use and are asking how to implement it in code, this is the right site to ask. Since it sounds like you don't yet know how you want to define outliers, I would suggest stats.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Or maybe there are no points that merit investigation. If this is an assignment, you should ask your instructor for clarification. There is no universal definition for outliers. We can not know what the intention of the assignment is.

Comment: ok thank you @josliber I shall do that.

Comment: @MrFlick it is an assignment although as it is marked we can not ask the lecturer for advice :( I may ask her though. Thank you both!

Comment: Would  upvote @MrFlick's comment a few more times if I could, really says it all. If instructor has something in mind, they should have conveyed that information sometime before assigning the exercise (maybe you need to look back at your class notes??)

Answer (score 1):

Well, "outlier" means only "something which has low probability under an assumed model for the data". The simplest assumption is that the data are normally distributed. Low probability for normally distributed data means anything in the tails. In the tails means data that are more than a few (let's say two) standard deviations away from the mean.

So this leads to a pretty simple procedure. Calculate the mean via the R function `mean` and the standard deviation via `sd`. Then look at any points which are less than mean minus twice the s.d. or more than mean plus twice the s.d. These will be a few at the left tail and a few at the right tail. Is there something interesting about these data? That's what your instructor is asking.

Of course, what counts as an outlier depends entirely on the model assumed for the data -- if you change the model, you'll change the outliers. So it's important to spell out what your model is, and be prepared to change it if somebody (e.g. your instructor) suggests a different one.

Comment: Thank you this is great i shall try that now :)!

Comment: @MollieKilpatrick On looking at the problem again, I see that you have two variables, not just one. The general approach is the same. Compute the mean and covariance (via `mean` and `cov` respectively) and use those to compute the probability of each point under the assumption that the data have a joint Gaussian (normal) distribution. Sort the data according to probability under the model and look at the ones which have low probability. You can look at a scatterplot and visually identify outliers as well -- the business about "low probability under the model" is just a formalization of that.